# Why was Manifest deprecated? When should I use ClassTag and when should I use TypeTag

Tags: scala

I have several questions on `Manifest` and `TypeTag`. I understand that JVM does not know about Generics and erases the types. So I cannot do this

```
def factoryForAll[T] = new T // will not compile. Runtime doesn't know what T is
```

Scala compiler could transfer information about types to runtime using `Manifest` (now deprecated). `Manifest` has methods like `erasure` which contains information about types. So I could do following to create objects of a generic type T

```
def factoryForall[T](implicit ev:Manifest[T]) = ev.erasure.newInstance

scala> factoryForAll[String]
res1:Any=""

scala> class C
defined class C

scala> factoryForAll[C]
res5: Any = C@52cb52bd
```

**Question 1 - Interesting, it doesn't work for Int (or Float)? Why?**

```
scala> factoryForAll[Int]
java.lang.InstantiationException: int
```

**Question 2 - Why was Manifest deprecated? I understand that the newer version, `TypeTag` has richer information but I do not understand what were the shortcomings in Manifest**

**Question 3 - Scala 2.12 still has `Manifest` class (https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/reflect/Manifest.html). If `Manifest` are bad, why do Scala still has it? The documentation refers to using  `Manifest` to create `Arrays` of Generic types but the Arrays could be implemented by `ClassTag` as well. So why does Scala still has `Manifest`?**

```
scala> def makeArray[T](len:Int)(implicit ev:ClassTag[T]) = new Array[T](len)
makeArray: [T](len: Int)(implicit ev: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])Array[T]

scala> makeArray[String](4)
res39: Array[String] = Array(null, null, null, null)

scala> makeArray[Int](4)
res40: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0)

scala> val al = makeArray[List[Int]](2)
al: Array[List[Int]] = Array(null, null)

scala> al(0) = List(1)

scala> al(1) = List(2,3)
```

Coming to `TypeTag`, there are 3 types. Referring to Scala documentation (http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) and a tutorial on Medium (https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/overcoming-type-erasure-in-scala-8f2422070d20), I understand that `TypeTag` and `ClassTag` have different use cases. ClassTag cannot differentiate between types beyond 1st level of erasure.

```
//method to extract a type from a collection
def extractType[T](col:Iterable[Any])(implicit ev:ClassTag[T]) = {
val it =col.iterator
while (it.hasNext) {
val el = it.next
el match {
case x:T => println("got T")
case _ => println("not T")
}}}

extractType: [T](col: Iterable[Any])(implicit ev: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])Unit

scala> extractType[Int](List(1,2,3,"hello"))
got T
got T
got T
not T

scala> extractType[List[Int]](List(List(1),List(2),List(3),List("hello")))
got T
got T
got T
got T //this should be not T
```

**Question4: If `ClassTag` cannot differentiate between 1st level of erasure, why do I get the following error when I try to add a `String` in a `List[Set[Int]]`. Isn't `Int` erased?**

```
scala> def makeArray[T](len:Int)(implicit ev:ClassTag[T]) = new Array[T](len)
makeArray: [T](len: Int)(implicit ev: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])Array[T]

scala> val al = makeArray[List[Set[Int]]](2)
al: Array[List[Set[Int]]] = Array(null, null)

scala> al(0) = List(Set(2))

scala> al(1) = List(Set("2"))
<console>:28: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("2")
 required: Int
       al(0) = List(Set("2"))
                        ^
```

Question5 - why in the earlier example  `extractType[List[Int]](List(List(1),List(2),List(3),List("hello")))`, Scala couldn't distinguish `String` from `Int` but it distinguished between `al(0) = List(Set(2))`
and `al(1) = List(Set("2"))`

**Question 6 - How do I change the `extractType` function such that I can check embedded types. I know I have to use TypeTag but I do not know how to check the type of the element in the collection.**

```
def extractType[T](col:Iterable[Any])(implicit ev:TypeTag[T]) = {
    println("class is "+ev.mirror.runtimeClass) //I suppose in TypeTag, runtime is here
    val it =col.iterator
    while (it.hasNext) {
    val el = it.next
    el match {
        case x:T => println("got T") //this doesn't compile. What should I check for?
        case _ => println("not T")
    }}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Question 1: `Int` and `Float` aren't represented by classes in JVM (though they have corresponding `Class` objects), let alone ones which have parameterless constructors. Despite the `forAll` in the name, this works for a very limited set of types.

Question 2: `Manifest` mixes up concerns which `ClassTag` and `TypeTag` separate.

Question 3: if you look at the source of `Manifest`, it says

> ```
> // TODO undeprecated until Scala reflection becomes non-experimental 
> // @deprecated("use scala.reflect.ClassTag (to capture erasures) or scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag (to capture types) or both instead", "2.10.0")
> ```

Question 4/5: this error comes from the static type `al: Array[List[Set[Int]]]`. No runtime information provided by `ClassTag` or `TypeTag` is involved.

Question 6: using only the standard library you can't. But see [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#type-safe-cast).