# What is the meaning of a generic type like "C: ClassTag : Manifest"?

Tags: scala, implicit, generic-programming, context-bound, classtag

I found some snippets as follow:

```scala
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

import scala.io.Source
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class ConfigLoader[C: ClassTag : Manifest](filePath: String) {

  def loadFromFile(): C = {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    parse(Source.fromFile(filePath).mkString, false).extract[C]
  }

}
```

What's the meaning of generic type like `C: ClassTag : Manifest`?

Comment: The type(s) represented by type parameter `C` are "context bound" to membership in both `ClassTag` and `Manifest` type classes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47488748/why-was-manifest-deprecated-when-should-i-use-classtag-and-when-should-i-use-ty

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `C: ClassTag` is a shorthand for `(implicit ct: ClassTag[C])`.

I.e. the full form of the class constructor is

```scala
class ConfigLoader[C](filePath: String)(implicit ct: ClassTag[C], m: Manifest[C]) { ... }
```

In practical terms, it means that inside the definition of `ConfigLoader`, instances of `ClassTag[C]` and `Manifest[C]` are required, and thus they have to be provided as arguments to the constructor.